# как решить задание по Map?

Tags: java, map

```
import java.util.Map;

class Playground {
    /**
     * Given a map of countries and their population calcualte 
     * average population in the country.
     * 
     * Example:
     *  calculateAveragePopulation({}) => 0
     *  calculateAveragePopulation({"Ukraine", 42_000_000}) => 42_000_000
     *  calculateAveragePopulation({"Ukraine", 42_000_000
                                    "Moldova", 3_500_00}) => 22_750_000
     */ 
    private static int calculateAveragePopulation(Map<String, Integer> population) {
        // WRITE YOUR CODE BELOW THIS LINE
        return 0;
        // WRITE YOUR CODE ABOVE THIS LINE
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Map<String,Integer> data =
            new HashMap<String, Integer>(){{
                this.put("Ukraine", 100);
                this.put("Moldova", 50);
                this.put("China", 9999);
    }};
    //1
    double res = data.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .mapToInt(e -> e.getValue())
            .average()
            .getAsDouble();
    System.out.println("variant 1 = " + res);
    //2
    double sum = 0.0;
    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> elem : data.entrySet()) {
        Integer count = elem.getValue();
        sum += count;
    }
    sum /= data.size();
    System.out.println("variant 2 = " + sum);
```